# How to statically type function that returns array 1 to n

Tags: typescript, static-typing

I'm trying to make a function that returns an array of numbers, from 0 to n, but I want the returned type to also be the known array statically.

```js
const makeFoo = (n: number) => [...Array(n).keys()];
const foo1 = [0, 1, 2] as const; // readonly [0, 1, 2]
const foo2 = makeFoo(3); // number[]
console.log(foo1); // [0, 1, 2]
console.log(foo2); // [0, 1, 2]
```

While `foo1` and `foo2`, have the same value at runtime, their types are different.

How do I define `makeFoo`'s return type to be like `foo1`? (`readonly [0, 1, ... n]` where `n` is also known statically e.g. `makeFoo = <T extends number>(n: T) => ...`)

Comment: what is the maximum value for `n`?

Comment: Ideally `n` should be unbound, but practically for my specific use-case it can be a positive integer less than 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [recursive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/recursive-type-references) helper type which computes the return type based on a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#handbook-content) argument. However, you will need a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) for that (I don't think there's a way without) since `[...Array(n).keys()]` will always be inferred as `number[]`.

```
type MakeFoo<N extends number, R extends any[] = []> = R["length"] extends N
  ? R
  : MakeFoo<N, [...R, R["length"]]>;

function makeFoo<N extends number>(n: N): MakeFoo<N> {
  return [...Array(n).keys()] as MakeFoo<N>
}

const foo3 = makeFoo(3);
//    ^? const foo3: [0, 1, 2]
const foo100 = makeFoo(100);
//    ^? const foo100: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... , 99]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgawgMQPaoDwDkoQB7AQB2AJgM5RECuAtgEYQBOANFAEq4HHlRxEgBtALpQAvFGEA+MewEAiADbEA5sAAWckfkKkKWAFBQoAfnaGoALliIU6bKwEA6Z21Zt5Soqo1ChkgNz6+gBmVEQAxsAAlqhEUDQ2aJg42twU1PRMkgAURFZYAJRW8EhJ2NIA3uaMEMBUjHFOzgCCjIxwILkFjkggZNkFInAUJbbJkvoAvkHhsWTAUMHoAMwyCaXo2csFgQD0u0ZGAHrG+rNE84voAIwADLdriZt3tzv6+4dQJ0A)

---

Caveat: This only works for a maximum of 999 items. Anything above will resolve to `any`.

```
const foo1000 = makeFoo(1000);
//              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
```

Comment: This breaks if I do something like this [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgawgMQPaoDwDkoQB7AQB2AJgM5RECuAtgEYQBOANFAEq4HHlRxEgBtALpQAvFGEA+MewEAiADbEA5sAAWckfkKkKWAFBQoAfnaGoALliIU6bKwEA6Z21Zt5Soqo1ChkgNz6+gBmVEQAxsAAlqhEUDQ2aJg42twU1PRMkgAURFZYAJRW8EhJ2NIA3uaMEMBUjHFOzgCCjIxwILkFjkggZNkFInAUJbbJkvoAvkHhsWTAUMHoAMwyCaXo2csFgQD0u0ZGAHrG+rNE84voAIwADLdriZt3tzv6+4dQJ0GhEdGxUFiEAAKqgsNhODoeBkGIwcnkoIUoFUjOdLgAvJioACqRGiChw4nWYy6gSMH2Op1RcwWUVIUXCEAo4kxjBxeKiBMcCTA2SiYmkUQA1Nc3uSDpTqrV6nE6SQGUzAtMgA)